# Export iGoogle RSS and Import into liferea

Tags: rss, liferea, google

I use igoogle for my rss reader, now i need to use Liferea on my Desktop and i need to Export my iGoogle rss and Import into liferea. I was trying export my rss from iGoogle (The default export format is .xml) but when i tried to import into  Liferea I get this error message 
[image]
is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm absolutely positive that any computer-related problems you face are caused by the karmic consequences of choosing to use Comic Sans for your system font. Rectify that first, and then work on the other problems!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i didn't know about that i will change that thanks anyway.

Comment: @frabjous When people come here looking for help, they might be more immune to sarcasm than they normally would be. @Achu Comic Sans has nothing to do with this. Feel free to keep using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own OPML file by following the next procedure:

1. Make an empty file and name it
   "opml.xml" (or whatever you wish but
   remember to use the ".xml" extension
   for the file.
2. Open the file using your favorite
   editor. (I prefer the usage of
   bluefish but you can use gedit for
   the code recognition and
   highlighting).
3. Write the code as in this example:

[image: opml]
(unfortunately I can't place code here, so I put an image instead but you can gain access to an example of my current opml file in the next link: [opml file example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/71s3bsiklb6mnj4/opml.xml)

Then save the changes in the file and try to import this file instead of the direct rss xml file (in your case iGoogle-settings.xml)

Things to consider:

1. You can add as many xmlUrl's as you
   wish, one line at once (starting
   from the "< outline ...")
2. xmlUrl must be a valid address. If
   you are using this example for a
   "one-time import", you can use local
   places by using just the file name,
   in which case both the opml file and
   the rss source must be placed in the
   same location.
3. I suggest you to try the opml file
   to get the connection to your web
   rss feed, in which case you should
   use the remote address for the xml
   file.

I don't have my mind fully in the topic, so I will probably edit this in order to add further details on demand.

I hope that the creation of this file will help you to do what you wish.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/export-igoogle-feeds-to-opml.html) convert to opml and then import using Lifrerea.